# achieving 3NF in MySQL without losing query speed?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Ima practicing making databases with SQL for the first time, and am starting with making an ER diagram before I actually start writing any queries. I want to try achieve 3NF, and not sure if I'm fully successful based on an example scenario I am trying from. Also is 3nf always the best normalization to use for query speed?

Answer (score 3):

Normalization has nothing to do with query speed. You can make queries that have high performance if you use full normalization, even if the queries need to do joins. I see joins used between relational tables in very high-performance production systems regularly.

Normalization is about *eliminating data anomalies*, that is, making your data model prevent weird cases where the data disagrees with itself.

Typically, you should optimize queries using indexes that are chosen carefully to support the specific queries you need to run with high performance. You can't choose indexes without knowing which queries you need to have the best performance.

That's enough to give your database plenty of performance in 90% of cases. If that's not enough, you might need to use denormalization or caching or sharding or other techniques of relieving performance bottlenecks.

But IMHO, you should start with a database that has been normalized. That will make it the most resistant to data anomalies, and it will also make it support the broadest variety of query types.

Use optimizations only if you experience a performance problem, because most types of optimizations make your code more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, makes more sense now. Could you also tell me if my er diagram is good for my scenario and does it fully conform by 3NF ? thank you.

Comment: You should probably read up on normalization yourself and understand what it means. It should be covered in any good book on relational database design. Or you can read the wikipedia summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization